# How do I import swift class into project?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am creating a basic app and I'm using `parse.com` to handle the backend stuff. I decided to create a custom class named `ParseHelper.swift` to handle all of my Parse interactions. I did assign all the variables as `static` yet I'm only able to access them if I do `import ParseHelper` at the top of my view controller. The issue is, I'm still getting a build error stating `No such module ParseHelper` although all my references aren't an issue, but once I remove the import statement I get 9 errors because it's no longer recognizing the references to the ParseHelper class.

Screenshot with import statement: (1 error)

[image: 1 error]

Screenshot without import statement: (9 errors)

[image: 9 error]

```
 override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    // Configure the PFQueryTableView
    self.parseClassName = ParseCandidateClass
    self.textKey = ParseCandidateName
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = false
}
```

The `ParseCandidateClass` and `ParseCandidateName` are both throwing use of unresolved identifier.

Comment: Verify all the files in the project have the correct Target Membership. Click a file on the left panel to bring it up in Xcode, then check the file inspector on the right side panel and make sure the Target Membership is selected for each target. This is a guess, but I remember getting errors when I was using Parse and did not have my files in the test target.

Comment: first screenshot is not loading. also please show some code of the lines in which errors are occurring.

Comment: Posted an example of two lines that are giving the errors.